# Is there any standalone EJB container that drops into non-j2ee web servers?

Tags: java, webserver, ejb

Right now I am using a web-server which does not contain EJB container.  If my application needs EJB container, how could I add one?

Comment: What kind of web server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really mean *into*? If yes, then maybe have a look at [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) (the EJB Container implementation for Apache Geronimo). But I can't say that it's widely used.

Actually, why not just replacing your servlet container with a full Java EE server if you need EJBs, I don't get it, something like JBoss AS or GlassFish.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) and [EasyBeans](http://wiki.easybeans.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) are open-source EJB containers that can be dropped into Tomcat or other servers / applications.

But, you should describing what you need this for... because if you need EJBs specifically, you're probably better off going with a full app server (JBoss, Glassfish, Weblogic, etc.). If you're just using it for persistence, you're probably better off using some other persistence technology (Hibernate, iBatis, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

JBoss is an open source J2EE server. So if for some reason you can't just use it, you could take the EJB container and graft it into something else. Probably not a small job.

Answer (score 0):

Too litte information on your architecture to give a decent answer.

Anyway chances are good you already apache as web server, you can simply connect using mod_jk to the embeddd tomcat in jboss. 
This configuration will use the Apache JServ Protocol (AJP) for communication between Apache and Tomcat.

A description on which config files you have to fiddle about is [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss)